# CsvHelper - Perform logic while reading records

Tags: csvhelper

I'd like to apply logic while reading a file, such as cleaning a string of special characters, or determining the difference between two dates if a field is blank.

I've tried this in my map:

```
public InboundPlacementMap()
    {
        AutoMap();
        Map(m => m.HomePhone).ConvertUsing(
            rec =>
            {
                return CleanPhoneNumber(rec.HomePhone);
            });

        Map(m => m.LengthOfStay).Name("Length of Stay").ConvertUsing(
            row =>
            {
                if (row.LengthOfStay > 0)
                    return (int)row.LengthOfStay;
                return (row.AdmitDate - row.DischargeDate+500).Days;
            });
    }

    private string CleanPhoneNumber(string phone)
    {
        //Do some logic to remove characters, etc.
        return phone;
    }
```

(In reality, CleanPhoneNumber sits in a different library which is used across projects.) But calling that had a smell to it which I didn't like, as well as it not seeming to work:

```
 Map(m => m.PatHomePhone).ConvertUsing(rec =>
    { return PamUtility.Utilities.CleanPhoneNumber(rec.PatHomePhone); });
```

In my method where I'm reading, I'm using GetRecords<>() to read everything at once. Am I better off reading the records one by one, and performing my logic as after I read each one? (That seems messy to me.)

```
            List<InboundPlacementFileRecord> allRecords = new List<InboundPlacementFileRecord>();
        using (TextReader textReader = File.OpenText(fileToRead))
        {
            var csv = new CsvReader(textReader);
            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = "|";
            csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
            csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = 
                        header => header.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated= null;
            csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<InboundPlacementMap>();
            allRecords = csv.GetRecords<InboundPlacementFileRecord>().ToList();
        }
```

EDIT:
For reference, here is what the record-by-by record would look like, which if there is more logic to perform, would rapidly get ugly, hence my desire to put it in the mapping:

```
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                var record = csv.GetRecord<InboundPlacementFileRecord>();

                record.LengthOfStay=(record.LengthOfStay>0)? record.LengthOfStay : 
                    (int)(record.DischargeDate-record.AdmitDate).TotalDays;

                // ... other logic here ...

                allRecords.Add(record);
            }
```

(Using latest CsvHelper, 7.1.0 at the time of this question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. Doing everything in a mapping is fine. Doing it inline is fine also. Another option instead of `ConvertUsing` is to create a custom type converter. You can use one of the built in ones as an example. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/BooleanConverter.cs

`GetRecords<T>()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` that will `yield` records. That means it will only pull one record on each iteration, so you don't have to worry about all the data being in memory. If you do something like `ToList()` or `Count()`, it will pull all the records into memory, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I ended up cleaning up the code enough by refactoring into smaller methods and making it look pretty nice.  I will look at the converters for future changes.  I missed a number of those by using nuget instead of going through the source. :D